# Flutuar elementos com CSS Grid

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, grid, flexbox

Bom dia amigos. Estou com o seguinte problema: preciso fazer os elementos flutuarem com CSS Grid sem ter uma row especifica definida. Por exemplo, na imagem a seguir, não deveria existir aquele espaço cinza, o elemento logo abaixo deveria vir para cima para cobrir este espaço, como se fosse algo fluido, tipo um masonry.js.

Na div que cerca os elementos possuo o seguinte código: 
`display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50% );
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(120px, auto);`

E os elementos azuis eu somente organizei com: 
`grid-column: 1/2`
ou
`grid-column: 2/2`.

[image: Disposição dos elementos]

Comment: Cara editei a resposta e coloquei dois exemplos práticos, um com e outro sem o grid-auto-flow acho que vai ficar mais fácil de visualizar comu funciona, mas qq coisa me fala que te ajudo.

Comment: Perfeito cara, muito obrigado mesmo, eu tinha visto essa propriedade mas não parei pra estudá-la a fundo. Muito obrigado mesmo por me ajudar a entender!

Comment: Cara Grid é muito novo e tb estou aprendendo um pouco rss. Estou fazendo uns testes aqui pq acho que quando eles tem o height definido da errado, só funciona se o conteúdo de dentro da div for grande. Mas seu eu ver algo edito a resposta e te falo

Comment: Cara inclui um exemplo no final da minha resposta que em vez do dense ele usa  `grid-auto-flow:row;` nesse modelo deu certo, mas o dense tb pode ser muito útil! No youtube tem algum material sobre isso

Comment: Estou quase conseguindo. O problema é que preciso que fique com a altura relativa ao conteúdo da div. Ele parece ficar relativo a DIV ao lado, e acaba aumentando todas da linha.

Comment: Então eu tinha notado isso, por isso comentei ai encima e coloquei os outros exemplo no final da resposta. Mas edita a sua pergunta, e coloca o código html/css do grid que vc tem até o momento que posso te dar uma força. Tente substituir `grid-auto-flow:row dense; pàra `grid-auto-flow:row;` e veja o comportamento que vai apresentar.

Comment: Cara fiz uns testes e parece que esse é o comportamento padrão do Grid Layout. Quando o conteúdo é maior que a altura os outros elementos que está na row acompanham a altura do elemento mais alto. E o dense é o mais indicado para "encaixar" as peças do grid mesmo... e se vc diminuir o height na mão por exemplo ai o espaço vazio volta. O grid vc deve interferir o menos possível height e width, vc deve trabalhar na altura da row e largura das column de preferencia.

Comment: Mas se vc não precisa exclisivamente do display:grid, da uma olhada aqui que pode te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316223/organizar-divs-em-blocos-uma-sobre-a-outra/316927#316927

Comment: Eu estava usando o CSS Columns, mas ele estava com um problema, e algumas pessoas relataram que era melhor o CSS Grid. Usei o exemplo que vc postou para exemplificar de maneira correta: https://codepen.io/jcdacampo/pen/qyjWzR.

Como vimos, o problema esta na altura do box 2 e 3, que não podem acompanhar a altura do 1. Tentei alterar o atributo grid-auto-flow de todas as maneiras, mas não funciona. Como vc disse, talvez este seja mesmo o comportamento padrão do CSS Grid.

Comment: Complementando: ao usar CSS Columns com a propridade `column-count: 2` os elementos inferiores ficam desta maneira: https://imgur.com/a/Tqcrw2V. Eles até ficam fluidos, mas parecem ficar "bugados" na parte inferior. Veja que o último quadrado deveria estar alinhado na direita, pois é onde tem maior espaço.

Comment: Pois é, no Grid as definições são mais voltadas para coluna/lina e não se usa muito variações de altura entre as células pois eles são atreladas por default. Já com o column-count é difícil controlar onde o conteúdo vai ser quebrado, mas com o break-inside da pra tentar impedir que uma div seja partida em duas pelo menos... Acho que só com CSS isso é o máximo que se consegue chegar do masonry infelizmente. Se eu ver algo que resolva isso perfeitamente eu comento aqui pra vc

Comment: Pois é, tem razão. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela ajuda e tempo disponibilizado com o problema.

Comment: Bom dia amigo, volto para dizer que consegui resolver o problema com CSS Columns. O que estava atrapalhando era meu animate.css que setava um height para a animação slideInUp e por isso bugava as columns. Deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo jovem! Sucesso com o projeto, qq coisa estamos ai!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc precisa ajustar a propriedade `grid-auto-flow` para `row dense`, assim todo elemento do Grid vai tentar se ajustar nos espaços em "vazios"

Aqui vc pode ler e ver alguns exemplos práticos do `grid-auto-flow` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-auto-flow.asp

Segue um exemplo. Repare que o `n4` deveria ficar após o `n3`, porém ele sobe pro espaço vazio que o `n3` deixou, pois o n3 começa na segunda coluna e não na primeira.

Exemplo com a propriedade `grid-auto-flow: row dense;` aplicada:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item3 { grid-column: 2 / 3; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50% );
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(120px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding:20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <p>O valor "dense" no grid-auto-flow faz o efeito que vc precisa </p>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">1</div>
      <div class="item2">2</div>
      <div class="item3">3</div>
      <div class="item4">4</div>
    </div>
```

---

Exemplo `SEM` a propriedade  aplicada:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.item3 { grid-column: 2 / 3; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50% );
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(120px, auto);
  /* grid-auto-flow: row dense; */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding:20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
    <p>SEM no grid-auto-flow</p>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">1</div>
      <div class="item2">2</div>
      <div class="item3">3</div>
      <div class="item4">4</div>
    </div>
```

---

Exemplo mais complexo **com dense** feito por Wes Bos

```css
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
      grid-auto-flow: dense;
    }
    .item:nth-child(6n) {
      background: cornflowerblue;
      grid-column: span 6;
    }
    .item:nth-child(8n) {
      background: tomato;
      grid-column: span 2;
    }
    .item:nth-child(9n) {
      grid-row: span 2;
    }
    .item18 {
      background: greenyellow !important;
      grid-column-end: -1 !important;
    }
    .item {
      background: silver;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item2">2</div>
    <div class="item item3">3</div>
    <div class="item item4">4</div>
    <div class="item item5">5</div>
    <div class="item item6">6</div>
    <div class="item item7">7</div>
    <div class="item item8">8</div>
    <div class="item item9">9</div>
    <div class="item item10">10</div>
    <div class="item item11">11</div>
    <div class="item item12">12</div>
    <div class="item item13">13</div>
    <div class="item item14">14</div>
    <div class="item item15">15</div>
    <div class="item item16">16</div>
    <div class="item item17">17</div>
    <div class="item item18">18</div>
    <div class="item item19">19</div>
    <div class="item item20">20</div>
    <div class="item item21">21</div>
    <div class="item item22">22</div>
    <div class="item item23">23</div>
    <div class="item item24">24</div>
    <div class="item item25">25</div>
    <div class="item item26">26</div>
    <div class="item item27">27</div>
    <div class="item item28">28</div>
    <div class="item item29">29</div>
    <div class="item item30">30</div>
  </div>
```

Exemplo mais complexo, mas **sem o dense** ele usa `grid-auto-flow:row;`

```css
.container {
  --gridgap:16px;
  --boxheight:100px;
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:var(--gridgap);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow:row;
  max-width:600px;
}

.box {
  outline:1px solid black;
  padding:8px;
  height:var(--boxheight);
}

.box.tall2  {
  height:calc(var(--boxheight)*2 + 2*var(--gridgap));
  grid-row-end:span 2
}

.box.tall3  {
  height:calc(var(--boxheight)* + 4*var(--gridgap));
  grid-row-end:span 3
}

.box.tall4  {
  height:calc(var(--boxheight)*4 + 6*var(--gridgap));
  grid-row-end:span 4
}
```

```html
<section class='container'>
  <section class='box'>Box 1</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 2</section>
  <section class='box tall2'>Box 3</section>
  <section class='box tall3'>Box 4</section>
  <section class='box tall4'>Box 5</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 6</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 7</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 8</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 9</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 10</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 11</section>
  <section class='box'>Box 12</section>
</section>
```

*Fonte:* https://codepen.io/fch/pen/vmqBpa